# the conditional breakpoint doesn't work for goland

Tags: go, goland

I set the conditional breakpoint for string sql which contains the "PROCESSLIST"  by strings.Contains(sql, "PROCESSLIST")  ,how it didn't work,as it still suspended even the sql does not contains the "PROCESSLIST" , see below:

[image]

Comment: According to this topic: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1803
You may not use function call inside breakpoint conditional.

Comment: thanks,I used the sql=="PROCESSLIST" directly solving the issue.

Comment: Please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10248/Conditional-breakpoints-are-not-working-on-function-calls-function-calls-not-allowed-without-using-call and Delve issue: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1766